# Using a router on a specific route

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

the problem is this:
My Angular application is served as follows via the server (it is the server that gives static html file)
localhost:3000/my-app
This URL provides index.html and scripts with my angular application

How do I configure routes inside my application so that when I go to localhost:3000/my-app/first-component
did a specific component open?

My current routes in Angular app:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "app",
    component: FirstComponent
  },
  {
    path: "app/second-component",
    component: SecondComponent
  }
];
```

My express server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'scripts')))

app.all('/app', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

After i run localhost:3000/app i get my first component, but when i try go to localhost:3000/app/second-component it doesn't work

Console error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: Please read https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 1):

Your error is "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**".

Your issue may not be related to the routes.  I assume somewhere in your second-component.html file or other related file, you have an extra '**<**'.  Maybe an extra '**<**' around some tag.  Or a syntax error in the **component.ts** file.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the path for the route as:

```json
{
  path: "my-app/first-component",
  title: "Unauthorized",
  component: FirstComponent
}
```

Also check out the [Angular Routing Guide](https://angular.io/guide/router), as it has a ton of helpful information about how to use modules to create nested routes, which is useful when you start to make more complex applications.

Comment: Yeah, i tried this, but in my express application it does not work

Comment: Updated description